# Notation of multiplicative derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, custom-notation

In the question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=non+newtonian, I use "dstar" as acronym to multiplicative derivative. But in the standard literature the symbol i $f^\star$. How can I, if it is possible define this type of symbol and use it --- or $D^\star$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Notation` package. You first need to run

```
Needs["Notation`"]
```

which brings up a palette that you can use to enter notation. Since this is hard to write down, I am posting a gif showing how it is done. Use <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>star</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to get the $\star$ symbol.

[image]